# Secret mount on Kubernetes container fails with security context (run as non-root user) added

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, mounted-volumes

I share a part of the manifest where I added security context added. If I remove the security context, it works fine. I try to use non-root user to up the container. Not sure, what I did wrong below

```
containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}                             
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 2000
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false            
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8010
              protocol: TCP                
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mount-jmx-secret
              mountPath: "etc/hello-world"                                                    
      volumes:
        - name: mount-jmx-secret
          secret:
            secretName: jmxsecret
            defaultMode: 0600
```

Comment: What's the error message? Can you post it? Thanks

Comment: @Rico I see status as terminated, reason as error, exit code as 1 when I run `kubectl describe` command. Is there other way to retrieve the error logs? I am sorry if I am asking basic question! I am new to kubernetes

Comment: @Rico, pod staus from `describe` command `hello-world:
    Container ID:   docker://d02219758c897d9727681bb48b112c19d89262a140f9f1d400806cb722dd05f1
 
    Port:           8010/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1    
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-2d8gx (ro)
      etc/hello-world from mount-jmx-secret (rw)`

Comment: how about the  output for `kubectl logs <pod-name>`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what mistake I made. It worked fine after couple of reinstalls of helm charts.
Changes I made, Added a new user to docker file

```
RUN useradd -u 8877 <user_name>(ram)
USER ram
```